# Calculate sum of decimals from separate tables for each year with latest entry

Tags: t-sql

How to get the sum of decimals from two tables.
Table A is holding only the current year value (per A.ID) and table B is holding the changes of the table A object including previous changes for the current year.

```
Table A:
"ID"     >> int (PrimaryKey), 
"Date"   >> datetime,
"AValue" >> decimal 

Objects of A:
1 | 12/02/2018 | 10.000
2 | 11/25/2018 | 20.000

Table B:
"ID"       >> int (PrimaryKey), 
"AObjID"   >> int (ForeignKey to Table A.ID), 
"Date"     >> datetime, 
"BValue"   >> decimal

Objects of B:
 1 | 1 | 08/06/2018 | 9.000 
 2 | 1 | 12/15/2017 | 10.000  *
 3 | 1 | 10/18/2017 | 8.000
 4 | 1 | 12/09/2016 | 10.000 *
 5 | 1 | 11/11/2016 | 5.000
 6 | 2 | 05/21/2018 | 13.000 
 7 | 2 | 12/19/2017 | 20.000 **
 8 | 2 | 08/04/2017 | 15.000 
 9 | 2 | 05/13/2017 | 15.000
10 | 2 | 12/25/2016 | 20.000 **
11 | 2 | 02/21/2016 | 15.000
12 | 2 | 11/09/2015 | 20.000 **
```

The result should sum together the current year AValue and all related BValues, where the latest entry of every year should be taken, except the current Year of A.

Case A.ID = 1 >> (Result = 30.000):

```
 A:      1 | 12/02/2018 | 10.000
 B:  2 | 1 | 12/15/2017 | 10.000 *
 B:  4 | 1 | 12/09/2016 | 10.000 *
```

Case A.ID = 2 >> (Result = 80.000):

```
 A:       2 | 11/25/2018 | 20.000
 B:   7 | 2 | 12/19/2017 | 20.000 **
 B:  10 | 2 | 12/25/2016 | 20.000 **
 B:  12 | 2 | 11/09/2015 | 20.000 **
```

Still struggling with this ... Any help appreciated! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @table_a table
(
    ID int,
    [Date] date,
    AValue decimal
);

declare @table_b table
(
    ID int,
    AObjID int,
    [Date] datetime,
    BValue decimal
);

insert into @table_a values
(1, '2018-12-02', 10.0),
(2, '2018-11-25', 20.0);

insert into @table_b values
(1, 1, '2018-08-06', 9.0),
(2, 1, '2017-12-15', 10.0),
(3, 1, '2017-10-18', 8.0),
(4, 1, '2016-12-09', 10.0),
(5, 1, '2016-11-11', 5.0),
(6, 2, '2018-05-21', 13.0),
(7, 2, '2017-12-19', 20.0),
(8, 2, '2017-08-04', 15.0),
(9, 2, '2017-05-13', 15.0),
(10, 2, '2016-12-25', 20.0),
(11, 2, '2016-02-21', 15.0),
(12, 2, '2015-11-09', 9.0);

with a_vals as (select null AID, ID, [Date], AValue, null rnum from @table_a where ID = 1)
select * from a_vals
union all
select * from
(
    select tb.ID, tb.AObjID, tb.[Date], tb.BValue,
           row_num = row_number() over (partition by tb.AObjID, year(tb.[Date])
                                        order by tb.[Date] desc)
    from @table_b tb inner join a_vals av on tb.AObjID = av.ID
        and year(tb.[Date]) < year(av.[Date])
) x
where x.row_num = 1
order by AID;
```

Comment: This was quick! Result list looks like expected! Thank you! Just one last question... before I dive deeper into your SQL. ;) How to get the sum result then, as like for A.ID = 1 >> 30 as a single decimal. Want to do a function for this.

Comment: @SiL3NC3 The output (in case `A.ID = 1`) is three rows. What output do you need to see the sum? Sum in every row? Or may be this will be one row? :)

Comment: Just one row, we need to get the sum only value as single decimal. :)

Answer (score 0):

I finished up with another CTE around to get the sum...
@JohnyL: Thank you for making me understand! :)

```
declare @table_a table
(
    ID int,
    [Date] date,
    AValue decimal
);

declare @table_b table
(
    ID int,
    AObjID int,
    [Date] datetime,
    BValue decimal
);

insert into @table_a values
(1, '2018-12-02', 10.0),
(2, '2018-11-25', 20.0);

insert into @table_b values
(1, 1, '2018-08-06', 9.0),
(2, 1, '2017-12-15', 10.0),
(3, 1, '2017-10-18', 8.0),
(4, 1, '2016-12-09', 10.0),
(5, 1, '2016-11-11', 5.0),
(6, 2, '2018-05-21', 13.0),
(7, 2, '2017-12-19', 20.0),
(8, 2, '2017-08-04', 15.0),
(9, 2, '2017-05-13', 15.0),
(10, 2, '2016-12-25', 20.0),
(11, 2, '2016-02-21', 15.0),
(12, 2, '2015-11-09', 20.0);

with a_vals as (select null as AID, ID, [Date],AValue, null as rnum from @table_a where ID =1), 
sum_vals as (
    select * from a_vals
    union all
    select * from
    (
        select 
        tb.ID, 
        AID = tb.AObjID, 
        tb.[Date], 
        tb.BValue,
        row_num = row_number() over (partition by tb.AObjID, year(tb.[Date]) order by tb.[Date] desc)
        from @table_b tb 
        inner join a_vals av 
        on tb.AObjID = av.ID and year(tb.[Date]) < year(av.[Date])
    ) x
        where x.row_num = 1)
SELECT Sum(AValue) FROM sum_vals
```